# Suppose $H:= \{\sigma \in G| \sigma(1) = 1\}$, if for any $j \in \{1,2,...,n\}$ $t_j\in G$ such that $t_j(1) = j$. Show that $|G| = n|H|.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Let G be a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_n$ in n letters. Consider the following subset of G:
$$H:= \{\sigma \in G| \sigma(1) = 1\}$$

Suppose that G acts on the set $\{1,2,...,n\}$ transitively in the sense that for any $j \in \{1,2,...,n\}$ there exists some $t_j\in G$ such that $t_j(1) = j$. Show that 
$$|G| = n|H|.$$

My attempt:

As long as I can prove that the coset $t_kH$ for $1\leq k\leq n$ are distinct then I am done. $t_iH = t_jH$ iff $t_j^{-1}t_i \in H$ iff $t_j^{-1}t_i(1) = (1)$.

Suppose that this is true. Then,$t_j^{-1}t_i(1) = t_j^{-1}(i) = 1$. Then $t_jt_j^{-1}(i) = t_j(1) =j$. But $t_jt_j^{-1}$ is the identity permutation. Hence, contradiction. All the cosets are distinct. Therefore, $|G| = n|H|$

Comment: You are right. (Actually $H$ is isomorphic to $S_{n-1}$)